# sending mail with nodemailer - email from field incorrect

Tags: node.js, express, pug, nodemailer

Trying to set up a contact form with nodemailer. Here's what's in my app.js:

```
// EMail configuration
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "myemailaddress",
        pass: "xxx"
    }
});

// CONTACT FORM
app.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
    res.render("contact");
});

app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
    var mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email, // sender address
        to: "myemailaddress", // list of receivers
        subject: req.body.subject, // Subject line
        text: req.body.message, // plaintext body
    }
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        }
        smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
    });
    res.render("contact", { success: "building web app" });
});
```

And my contact.jade template looks like this:

```
form#contact-form(action="/contact", method="POST")
div.span5
    p Full name:
        input#name(type="text", name="name")
    p Email address:
        input#email(type="email", name="email")
    p Subject:
        input#subject(type="text", name="subject")
    p Message:
        textarea#message(type="text", name="message", rows="5")
    p: button(type="submit") Send message
```

The email now works, but comes from myemailaddress rather than the one I enter into the email field on the template. Any ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gmail and many other email services don't allow you to send messages with various `FROM` field.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I'll put it in the body of the message text instead. Thanks for that.

Comment: Only thing you can modify is name of the sender, so `Joe Doe <myemailaddress@gmail.com>` may be `My mailing service <myemailaddress@gmail.com>`

Comment: Thanks @wachme! I'm pretty new to using email services. Do you have a short list of email providers who do allow this customization? Would Amazon SES be able to do this? And can you share the original docs or other resources that specify gmail doesn't do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use postmark, they provide an excellent api for sending emails and there is a node module for it (https://npmjs.org/package/postmark)