# nodemailer not sending and returning error

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, axios

I'm trying to setup a simple contact form using nodemailer. All i'm trying to do is send an email to my email from the contact form. My email is "myemail@mac.com"

When I do my axios post I get an error in the data object saying:  550 5.7.0 From address is not one of your addresses. but yet the status:200 and statusText:"OK"

When I use the same from email as the icloud email "myemail@mac.com" then it works ? I dont see anything where it says you have to use the same from address as the service address ?

**Axios post:**

```
  const request = axios.post('http://localhost:3002/send', {'name':John Doe,'email':meme@gmail.com'});
  request.then((result)=>{
      console.log("request = ", result);
  });
```

Error message from console.log("request = ", result);

```
error:{
 code:"EMESSAGE",
 command:"DATA",
 response:"550 5.7.0 From address is not one of your addresses.",
 responseCode:550
}
```

**nodemailer is my node.js**

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "iCloud",
  auth: {
    user: "myemail@mac.com",
    pass: "myemailpassword"
  }
})

    app.use('/send', function(req, res){
      var message = {
        from: req.body.email,
        to: 'myemail@mac.com',
        subject: 'Message From Portfolio Contact Form',
        //text: 'Plaintext version of the message',
        html: '<p>'+req.body.description+'</p>'
      };
      transporter.sendMail(message, function(error, info){
        if(error){
          res.json({error: error});
        }else{
          res.json({success: info.response});
        };
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configure nodemailer transport with iCloud Service and you are trying to send a mail with a gmail adresse.

```
from: req.body.email, // meme@gmail.com
to: 'myemail@mac.com'
```

Which logically produces the error:

> response:"550 5.7.0 From address is not one of your addresses."

You probably want to do the inverse.

Comment: When you say send I presume you mean the From address ? So the configured icloud service address has to be exactly the same email as the from attribute in the message ?  I'm not sure how changing the configured email to gmail would make a difference as it sates in the docs that you can use an icloud service. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can stick with iCloud, this is not a problem, but the From address need to be an authenticated user to the smtp service you use. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16944453/5156280

Comment: Ah ok got it. I'll just go with adding the senders email to the body of the email. I saw your link and tried to change the name part of the from address but that caused an issue also. '"Joe Doe" <myemail@mac.com>'. If I can change the name then it doesn't look so weird when receiving the email in your machines mail application as your own name.

Comment: So for example I changed the from name to be.  from: 'Contact Mailbox <myemail@mac.com>' but the mail still comes into my mailbox as my name because I'm using myemail@mac.com and apple mail is seeing this as me even thought I changed the name to Contact Mailbox. Cn't seem to find any way around that ?

Comment: Yeah that's happen to me too when I tried with a gmail account. I'm not a email specialist but I think it is a common practice to use a dedicated email adress for send from in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the help.